# How to handle basic, advanced, add on, and pro feature in Saas based software?

Tags: spring, hibernate, saas

We are working on new requirement where we need to enable features based on contract with the client. It`s a Saas based software and support multi tenancy. The software by default have basic features enabled.

Basic features

Customer management

Basic billing/invoicing

Notification via email

Payments

Advance feature

Notification over SMS

Workflow

Etc

All the client serviced by same software (Obviously same deployment ) but data will be stored on different database schema.

How to handle basic, advanced, add on, and pro feature in this case?

We are using spring and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should be handling these internally in your application so that the features like notification, workflow are marked as application features and for each tenant, there will be a mapping between the tenant id and the feature so that the tenant has access only to the features that he is subscribed to.

So, when a tenant or his user logs in to the system, we identify the features and the contents that he can access and then show them to the user. This is called as a tenant licensing system.

Also, whenever a feature is consumed, your code should be recording the tenant that consumed that feature and by how much and when and there can be cost associated with units of usage measurements.

For more detailed discussion, please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856952.aspx)

Though these are all explained in C#, there should be no hinderance in the conceptual understanding.